wkhtmltopdf (Odoo) wrong characters seen even if they're escaped but good on html source
I have to make a report on Odoo from scratch, not using the standard layout. I have some lines of the report that shows the currency symbol €. But the PDF is showing strange symbols. I tried to escape them with & a m p; and others escaped but still showing strange values. The HTML source is looking good.


I finally came to the solution: adding this line solved the issue.
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

